# NSURLCache is emptied when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlcache

i'm trying to implement a NSURLCache with AFHTTPRequestOperation, this is what i have done:

AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:50 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

....
    }
```

Then to use it i do this:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0f];
UIImage *image = [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:urlRequest];
if (image != nil) {
  //Cached image
} else {

AFHTTPRequestOperation *postOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
postOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[postOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  UIImage *image = responseObject;
  [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cacheImage:image forRequest:urlRequest];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[postOperation start];
```

}

the first time i open the view when there is the code above download the image and store it in the cache, then i close the view and i open it again and read it from the cache, instead if i close the app, and i try again the image is downloaded again, so how i can create a NSURLCache persistent?

**EDIT:**

I have tried what Duncan Bubbage suggest, and i have add a cache path instead of the nil, and i have do it in this way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    cachePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp_img"];

    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:50 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:cachePath];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

but i still cannot cache perstitently across session, what i have wrong? i have also check in the Finder the Cache Folder, and there is the temp_img folder, i have tried to create the folder manually with NSFileManager and then pass the path, but the folder temp_img remain empty...

Comment: Does anything get written to the cache directory while the app is running, which is then deleted, or is it simply that nothing is ever written?

Comment: nothing is ever written, no directory, no image nothing

Comment: Make sure path exists.

Comment: If i create it with nsfilemanager exist for sure, but the folder is always empty, Also the documentation say that if the folder doesn't exist it will be created, so i think that this is not the problem, anyone can help me?

Comment: Is it valid to set initWithMemoryCapacity:0? Try setting the memory capacity to the same size as the disk capacity. It may be that the memory capacity prevents the cache from ever being used. In that regards, your question here states "the first time i open the view when there is the code above download the image and store it in the cache". However, have you actually confirmed that the image is ever being cached, or would it be re-downloaded even during the current app session? May simply be your cache is not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is valid to set `diskPath:nil` when you are wanting to cache to disk persistently across sessions? The parameter is optional but that may only be for the use case of caching in memory only, in which case you'd expect to see what you're seeing here?

Alternatively, the [Apple documentation for this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/initWithMemoryCapacity:diskCapacity:diskPath:) states:

> NOTE
>
> In iOS, the on-disk cache may be purged when the system runs low on disk space, but only when your app is not running.

This could just be expected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have to purge the on disk cache when system runs low memory, or iOS do it automatically?

Comment: iOS will do this automatically, if the overall system (not just your cache) is short on free disk space.

Comment: i have tried to add the path, but doesn't work, i have update the question